# How can the Dispatcher-Property get null?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, winrt-xaml, dependency-properties, dispatcher

Windows 10 Build 10295/10332
Visual Studio 2015 Update 2

### Problem

I have the strange case that the **`Dispatcher`-property** of a control, in my case a simple `Button`, **gets `null`**.

This `Button` is **added at runtime by code** whereas another `Button` is **added in Xaml**.
Both share the **same `Parent`**.

Codewise I interact with them in exactly the same way. But after 2-5 code-interactions (setting `DependencyProperties` like `Style`) the code-Button all of a sudden has a **`Dispatcher`-value of `null`** whereas the **other is still set**!
Both are still part of the visual-tree.

### Question

How can the Dispatcher-value get null in the first place if both `Button`s are treated equally?

### Sideeffects

I suppose that this null-value leads to 2 exceptions I experience:

- `System.ExecutionEngineException` when calling `DependencyProperty.SetValue(...)` or
- `System.AccessViolationException` when using `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildCount(...)`

Comment: Could you share a [mcve]? Without a sample, it's hard to reproduce your issue.

Comment: It's not easy - I already tried that yesterday but had no success. I will try again tonight. Basically I set an attached DP and then walk the visual tree and reset other attached DPs (set to null). While walking the tree *some* controls don't have a Dispatcher assigned.